# Error en Python 3.7 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, codificación, python-3.7

En Python 3.7 estoy haciendo:

```
>>> from struct import pack as spack
>>> a1=spack("LLLL", 45129401,92367215,681285731,1710201)
>>> a1.encode('hex')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Pero como veis me da el error:

> 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: tiene el error al momento de hacer el encode!? intentaste con 'utf-8'.

Comment: hola, como podría hacer eso?

Comment: en ves de a1.encode('hex') utiliza a1.encode('utf-8')

Comment: no obtengo el mismo error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estamos hablando de [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode), es decir un método de objetos tipo cadena, sin embargo [`struct.pack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack) retorna un objeto de tipo `bytes` que, claramente lo menciona el error, no posee un atributo `encode`. El problema posiblemente se deba a que estás intentando usar código 2x con la versión 3x de Python. Si lo que buscas es convertir los bytes generados a una cadena hexadecimal, en vez de hacer `a1.encode('hex')` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
import codecs
print(codecs.encode(a1, 'hex_codec'))
```